# Pass json string as Route Parameter in .net core razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a action method which takes array[] as an argument as following

```
public IActionResult MyAction(string[] data)
{
   -- Further Implementation -- 
   return View(model);
}
```

In view side i am using following code, here i am using routing to pass data to controller.

```
 var array = JSON.stringify(cityList); --This is Json String which i wanter to pass 

-- want convert this json String into c# string.  

 window.location.href = "@Url.RouteUrl("PrintWorkAssignement",**Need to pass string**)";
```

> So is there any way that i can convert that json string into C# string, so that i can place it as a parameter and send it to controller ?

Comment: Have you checked this doc : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-5.0#collections ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you use `Url.RouteUrl` so I assume that you have an action to target by route name. Also that means you need to pass the route value to the bound parameter which is of type `string[]`. So in this case it's a complex type. The value will not be auto-converted for you. You need a custom `IModelBinder` with the input (raw) value of json, something like this:

```
public class JsonEnumerableBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        if (typeof(IEnumerable).IsAssignableFrom(bindingContext.ModelType))
        {
            var value = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.FieldName).FirstValue;
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value))
            {
                try
                {
                    var modelType = bindingContext.ModelType == typeof(IEnumerable) ? typeof(List<object>) :
                                    bindingContext.ModelType.IsGenericType &&
                                    bindingContext.ModelType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IEnumerable<>) ?
                                    typeof(List<object>).MakeGenericType(bindingContext.ModelType.GetGenericArguments()[0]) :
                                    bindingContext.ModelType;
                    bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(JsonSerializer.Deserialize(value, modelType));
                }
                catch
                {
                    bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Failed();
                }
            }
        }
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

Note that the model binder above can bind value to parameter of type `IEnumerable` like `string[]`, `List<T>`, ... So it's more general than your parameter type of `string[]`.

You can provide your custom model binder ***globally*** by using an `IModelBinderProvider`. However in this case I recommend using an explicit parameter-scope binding with the help of the `ModelBinderAttribute` like this:

```
public IActionResult MyAction([ModelBinder(typeof(JsonEnumerableBinder))] string[] data) { ... }
```

And here's how you pass in the value for the `Url.RouteUrl`:

```
//json is the json string you have
window.location.href = "@Url.RouteUrl("PrintWorkAssignement", new { data = json })";
```

Finally there is a note about the not-looking-good URL generated with a JSON being part of the path (a segment). Because as I said, you seem to bind your `data` with a route value which appears in the route pattern, something like this:

```
[Route("parent/{data}", Name = "PrintWorkAssignement")]
public IActionResult MyAction([ModelBinder(typeof(JsonEnumerableBinder))] string[] data) {...}
```

That would generate ugly URLs of course. So in such case you may want to use query string to bind value for your `data`. The json is appended at the end of the path (as a query string value) seem to look better. To use the query string, just remove the `{data}` part in the route pattern. The value will be appended as a query string and your custom `IModelBinder` still works. However if binding it as a query string, you have another option to make it work without having to pass a json and require a custom `IModelBinder` (as we apply above). The `string[]` can be bound from a set of query string variables each one of which is an item, like this `data[0]=abc&data[1]=xyz`. So that's the format you need (not a json) for your query string (and you don't need a custom `IModelBinder` anymore). First you need a javascript function to convert your array to a value of that format:

```
//just a simple function target an array of string
//you can build a more complex function (or find somewhere) which targets an object graph
function getQueryString(stringArray, paramName){
   return stringArray.map(function(e,i) { return paramName + "[" + i + "]=" + e;  })
                     .join("&");
}
```

Note that in `jQuery` you have the function `$.param` which should work, but for this case (format a string array), it somehow converts to the format like this `data[]=abc&data[]=xyz` (missing the indices). That format does not work and no value will be bound for you on the server-side (at least that's what I tested on `asp.net core 2.2`). Always include the indices for it to surely work.

Now with that function, you can change to use query string like this:

```
var queryString = getQueryString(yourStringArray, "data");

//your link built by query string, remember to remove the [ModelBinder(...)] on your action method
window.location.href = "@Url.RouteUrl("PrintWorkAssignement")?" + queryString;
```

Answer (score 0):

Array as query parameter should look like below:

```
www.test.com/api/testaction?data=first&data=second&data=third
```

Notice that name of the value should be same as name of the argument in the action method (`data`)